# Not able to set the height of CalendarTextField of jfxtras library

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, jfxtras

I am using CalendarTextField of jfxtras library in my project and applying css for it as well as setting prefHeight and prefWidth in fxml but the height applies only on the icon of field and the hight of field get adjust with font size.

FXML

```
<CalendarTextField fx:id="startDateField" prefWidth="230" prefHeight="32.0"/>
```

CSS

```
.CalendarTextField {
-fx-text-fill : #f00;
-fx-font-size: 24;
}

.CalendarTextField .icon{
-fx-image: url("../images/calender.png");
-fx-cursor:hand;
}
```